# Convergence in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of pairwise orthogonal vectors in a Hilbert space $H$.  Prove that the following are equivalent:
>
> a) $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|x_n\|^2<\infty$
>
> b) $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges in the norm topology of $H$
>
> c) $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty (y,x_n)$ converges for each $y\in H$.

- I got (a) implies (b).
- On (b) implies (c), let $y\in H$.  Then $(y,\sum_{n=1}^m x_n)=\sum_{n=1}^m (y,x_n)$ then take the limit as $m$ approaches infinity. Is this all that is needed?
- For c implies a, do we just replace $y$ with $x_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

For each $m\in\mathbb{N}$ consider $y=\sum\limits_{n=1}^m x_n$ and use that vectors $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are pairwise orthogonal. Think what will happen if $m\to\infty$.

**P.S.**

You can't replace $y$ by $x_n$, since $x_n$ can be diferent elements of $H$. Element $y$ can not be equal to all $x_n$ simultaneously!

Comment: thank you.  I figures it would not be that easy

Comment: actually, is such a y in H.  In assuming c, we do not know the series converges

Comment: @john, good observation, see edits to my answer